# add MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter without changing spring version

Tags: spring, maven

When I was trying to run my application I had an exception

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
```

In order to resolve it I added dependency to my `pom.xml`.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

However whole application is under `3.1.1.RELEASE` Spring version. So there potentially could be problems with some other parts of application due to version change.

Is there a way to provide dependency for this class without upgrading Spring version?

Stacktrace is rather big.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:188)
        at com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xx.handler.RestServiceInvocationHandler.<clinit>(RestServiceInvocationHandler.java:4
8)
        at com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xx.util.xxxxUtils.getService(xxxxUtils.java:45)
        at org.xxx.xxx.xxx.xx.service.ServiceImpl.init(ServiceImpl.java:32)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutow
ireCapableBeanFactory.java:1581)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCa
pableBeanFactory.java:1522)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapab
leBeanFactory.java:1452)
....
```

Comment: Can you add the full stacktrace and the relevant code?

Comment: Well...It's under multiple wrappers and utility classes from external dependecies. I just call one method from utility class.

Comment: Then add the stacktrace.

Comment: What's preventing you from updating Spring for the whole app? A change from 3.1.1 to 3.1.2 should not cause any incompatibilities.

Comment: I know that the should not be major changes between versions but  the question whether it's possible or not to import just specific class.

Comment: I added specific utils that use `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` in its implementation